# Import large database in php my admin

Tags: import, phpmyadmin

I have Wordpress website. I am importing large database into "**Php my admin**" but showing an error.

> You probably tried to upload a file that is too large. Please refer to documentation for a workaround for this limit

Could you please tell me how to fix it?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got SSH access, you can import it via WP-CLI:

https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/db/import/

`wp db import file.sql`

This can handle large imports fine.

Note: wp-cli must be installed on the server (check with `wp --info`)
and target database must be empty (check with `wp db check`). You must manually upload the `file.sql` import file via sftp/plesk/cpanel first.

Comment: Could anyone tell me simple process because i have not deep knowledge but if someone guide me then it would be best.

Thank You in advance.